# Is there a closed-form expression for the inverse of $f \left( x \right) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \mu_i \left( 1 - x \right)^{i - 1}$?

Tags: summation, inverse, inverse-function

I am trying to find the inverse of $f$, knowing that
\begin{equation}
  f \left( x \right) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \mu_i \left( 1 - x \right)^{i - 1}
\end{equation}
where $\sum_{i = 1}^n \mu_i = 1$, $x \in \left[ 0 , 1 \right]$.

It seems that $f$ is a bijection of $\left[ 0, 1 \right]$, so $f$ has an inverse. For example, it is easy to check that $f \left( x \right) = \frac{1 - \left( 1 - x \right)^n}{nx}$ is stricly monotonous, where $\mu_i = \frac{1}{n}$. However, even in this case, I am unsure of the existence of a closed-form solution for the inverse.

And I am just wondering if a closed-form exists in general.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you could find a closed form for the general case.

However, letting $t=1-x$, you could consider that
$$y= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \mu_i\,t^{i - 1}$$ is a Taylor expansion built around $t=0$ to $O(t^{n+1})$ and use series reversion for an *approximate* solution. This would give quite nasty things such as
$$t=z-\frac{\mu_3 }{\mu_2}z^2+\frac{2 \mu_3^2-\mu_2 \mu_4
  }{\mu_2^2} z^3+\frac{-5 \mu_3^3+5 \mu_2 \mu_4 \mu_3-\mu_2^2 \mu_5 }{\mu_2^3}z^4+
   \frac{14 \mu_3^4-21 \mu_2 \mu_4 \mu_3^2+6 \mu_2^2 \mu_5 \mu_3+3 \mu_2^2 \mu_4^2 }{\mu_2^4}z^5+\cdots \qquad\text{where} \qquad z=\frac{y-\mu_1}{\mu_2}$$

The case where $\mu_i = \frac{1}{n}\,\,\forall i$,  *it seems* that
$$t=z \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i z^i=\frac{z}{z+1}\left(1+(-1)^n z^{n+1} \right) \qquad\text{where} \qquad z=n y-1$$